# url_launcher throws MissingPluginException on flutter web after deployment

Tags: firebase, flutter-web, firebase-hosting, url-launcher

I want to open the system's email program from the browser and I do this by calling

```dart
TextSpan(
    text: 'support@company.de',
    style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyMedium!.copyWith(
         color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
         fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
    ),
    recognizer: TapGestureRecognizer()
                    ..onTap = () async {
                      await launchUrl(
                        Uri(
                          scheme: 'mailto',
                          path: 'support@company.de',
                        ),
                      );
                    })
```

When I test the code locally (also with --release builds) everything works fine but as soon as I deploy the app to firebase hosting it returns an

`Uncaught Error: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method launch on channel plugins.flutter.io/url_launcher)`

What's the difference between my local release builds and the one I upload to firebase hosting?
Why does it suddenly give me this MissingPluginException?

Comment: I think you can include `firebase` tags while it is specific with  firebase hosting

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem. Adding url_launcher_web as a dependency in my pubspec file solved the issue for me.
`flutter pub add url_launcher_web`

Comment: unfortunately, doesn't help in my case

Answer (score 0):

Found [this comment](https://www.reddit.com/r/flutterhelp/comments/11b2hdb/comment/jzx1ibk/) and it helped in my case:

> cleaning the build with "flutter clean" and rebuilding